# Update property of certain object inside array in state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, nested, state

I am trying to update my code: https://repl.it/@colegonzales1/HeftyJoyfulAbilities

I am trying to make my handleToggle function work properly. It is blank now for the sake of tinkering, but I have spent the last 2-3 hours trying to make it work to my own knowledge but I cannot figure out how to access a specific item in state. I know how to overwrite it all, but that is not what I want to do. Say I have:

```
this.state = {
  todos: [
    {
      title: 'Wash car',
      id: 1,
      done: false
    },
    {
      title: 'Go shopping',
      id: 2,
      done: false
    }
  ],
  inputValue: ''
}
```

How can I ONLY change the value of done on the 'Go shopping' todo, to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array.map to toggle the done flag only on the element which matches the clicked id as follows. The other properties of the todo are copied with an object spread:

```
handleToggle (e) {
  const id = parseInt(e.target.id,10)
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    todos: prevState.todos.map(t => t.id === id ? {...t, done: !t.done} : t)
  })) 
}
```

Comment: Why do you use todos: prevState? Why not just say todos: this.state.todos.map?

Comment: @ColeGonzales prevState is the new recommended way of accessing the current state before a state change. 
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/react-docs-now-recommends-using-function-with-prevstate-inside-of-setstate

Answer (score 1):

You can find the index of the object with the given `id` with `findIndex` and create a new array with a copy of this object in it with its `done` flag toggled.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      {
        title: "Wash car",
        id: 1,
        done: false
      },
      {
        title: "Go shopping",
        id: 2,
        done: false
      }
    ],
    inputValue: ""
  };

  handleToggle = id => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const todos = [...prevState.todos];
      const todoIndex = todos.findIndex(todo => todo.id === id);

      todos[todoIndex] = { ...todos[todoIndex], done: !todos[todoIndex].done };

      return { todos };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleToggle(2)}>
          Toggle todo with id 2
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```